# Clarification on T5 Model Pre-training Objective and Denoising Process

Tags: nlp, large-language-model

I am currently developing a T5 model (encoder-decoder architecture) from scratch for educational purposes. While working on this project, I've encountered some confusion regarding the pre-training objective, specifically the *denoising objective*. I would like to clarify my understanding and have some questions about the process.

Given the sentence:

> Thank you for inviting me to your party last week.

Based on my understanding, during the pre-training phase with a denoising objective, the model works as follows:

- **Encoder input**: `Thank you <X> me to your party <Y> week`
- **Decoder input**: `<X> for inviting <Y> last`
- **Decoder labels (true labels)**: `for inviting <Y> last <Z>`

Here are my questions:

1. Is my interpretation of how the encoder input, decoder input, and decoder labels are constructed correct?
2. In this setup, the model is expected to predict sentinel tokens (e.g., `<X>`, `<Y>`). Could this potentially introduce confusion for the model, for example, it may take the idea that it is possible for the word "last" to come after the token ? Or does the model naturally learn to interpret these situations correctly?

---

**Accordingly to the paper:**

[image: denoising objective]

> we process the sentence `Thank you for inviting me to your party last week.` The words `for`, `inviting` and `last` are randomly chosen for corruption. Each consecutive span of corrupted tokens is replaced by a sentinel token (shown as `<X>` and `<Y>`) that is unique over the example. Since `for` and `inviting` occur consecutively, they are replaced by a single sentinel `<X>`. The output sequence then consists of the dropped-out spans, delimited by the sentinel tokens used to replace them in the input plus a final sentinel token `<Z>`.